# DotNetNuke 7+ Plug-in FullCalendar's Scheduler

Tags: c#, fullcalendar, dotnetnuke

I have some error when i plug in the scheduler in DNN 7. So that, i can't use the scheduler to set up what i want to do.

Someone can tell me which step fail to let the plug-in can't use.

I just use this code to include the js file and css file.

```
<dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="/Plug-in/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.3.2/lib/fullcalendar.min.js" />
<dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="/Plug-in/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.3.2/lib/jquery.min.js" />
<dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="/Plug-in/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.3.2/lib/jquery-ui.min.js" />
<dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="/Plug-in/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.3.2/lib/moment.min.js" />
<dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="/Plug-in/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.3.2/scheduler.min.js" />

<dnn:DnnCssInclude runat="server" FilePath="/Plug-in/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.3.2/lib/fullcalendar.min.css" />
<dnn:DnnCssInclude runat="server" FilePath="/Plug-in/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.3.2/lib/fullcalendar.print.css" />
<dnn:DnnCssInclude runat="server" FilePath="/Plug-in/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.3.2/scheduler.min.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of the scripts according to the documentation.

First jquery, then moment.js, then fullcalendar, then scheduler. Jquery-UI should be after jquery itself.

```
<dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="/Plug-in/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.3.2/lib/jquery.min.js" />
<dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="/Plug-in/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.3.2/lib/jquery-ui.min.js" />
<dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="/Plug-in/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.3.2/lib/moment.min.js" />
<dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="/Plug-in/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.3.2/lib/fullcalendar.min.js" />
<dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="/Plug-in/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.3.2/scheduler.min.js" />
```

Comment: It still happen. Not much work for me.
thanks for your help,